# Node.js test fails - The specified procedure could not found, contextify.node?

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I am working on facebook flux [ToDo-MVC sample](https://github.com/facebook/flux), and running test as `npm test`, on Windows8.1, msys (64 bit), node v0.10.32 (or Command Prompt, node v0.12.7). It fails, followed by an error message saying `Error: The specified procedure could not found. \node_modules\jest-cli\node_modules\jsdom\node_modules\contextify\build\Release\contextify.node`.

App itself works fine. What is missing here?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone find this question:

This is due to I use node.js directly on msys, which cannot solve innate permission problems on Windows. Use Node Command Prompt bundled with the node.js download for Windows system instead (as the instruction says!).